# Validate XML: nodes of same name differentiated by attribute value

Tags: xml, powershell, xsd

I am trying to validate XML like this:

```
<tasks>
    <task type="copy">
        <source>PATH TO... source</source>
        <destination>PATH TO... destination</destination>
    </task>
    <task type="delete">
        <path>C:\*</path>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

with this XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name='tasks'>
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='task' type='Task_Copy' minOccurs='0'  maxOccurs='1' />
            <xs:element name='task' type='Task_Delete' minOccurs='0'  maxOccurs='1' />
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:complexType name='Task_Copy'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='source' type='xs:string' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            <xs:element name="destination" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name='type' type='xs:string' use="required" fixed="copy" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name='Task_Delete'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='path' type='xs:string' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name='type' type='xs:string' use="required" fixed="delete" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This results in a PowerShell error of:

> Error loading XML; Multiple definition of element 'task' causes the content model to become ambiguous.
> A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence.

Which seems to me to be saying that you cannot validate two nodes of the same name, with different inner XML based on the value of an attribute. And yet, that seems to be what `fixed="XXX"` is for.
And this is a VERY common thing in XML so far as I can tell, and not frowned upon at all. Not to mention that there is no ambiguity, I can have a Task of type A or a Task of type B, and the inner XML is different for each.
So, I hope I am just missing something obvious here. Otherwise the XSD 1.0 that Microsoft is still limiting us to is pretty limited in use, which would be unfortunate. Sure, I can move to `taskCopy` and `taskDelete` as node names, but it just seems like this should be possibly without that.

Comment: I don't now xsd that well, but it seems *"...can be uniquely determined **without** examining the content or attributes of that item"* is already the answer?

Comment: @marsze Agreed, it does seem to be the case. It just means that XSD is a bit crippled in functionality. And, I have seen situations where a Microsoft error seems to say something is impossible, or an error is in a particular place, and the message is totally wrong. So I figured check to be sure this wasn't just a bogus message.

Answer (score 0):

For those able to validate their documents with XSD 1.1, there is a solution, see below.

Whether or not Powershell is limited to XSD 1.0, and how to overcome this if that's the case, would rather be the topic of a separate question.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="tasks">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="task" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:alternative type="CopyTaskType" test="@type = 'copy'"/>
          <xs:alternative type="DeleteTaskType" test="@type = 'delete'"/>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="TaskType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="source" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="destination" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="typeAttrType"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:simpleType name="typeAttrType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="copy"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="delete"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="CopyTaskType">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="TaskType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="source" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          <xs:element name="destination" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="typeAttrType" use="required" fixed="copy"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="DeleteTaskType">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="TaskType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="typeAttrType" use="required" fixed="delete"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I could validate the OP's XML sample with this schema using Oxygen-XML.

The key feature needed from XSD 1.1 is `xs:alternative` inside the definition of the task element. From there, I define 2 alternatives, based on the value of the type attribute. These alternatives are typed (`CopyTaskType` and `DeleteTaskType`), and both types inherit from a base type `TaskType`. Each type restricts the base type with imposed/disallowed elements and fixed value for the type attribute.